# Why do generated graphs in NetworkX start at 0 and not 1?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm a novice in learning NetworkX. When I learned how to create a network via coding, taking network G as an example, the textbook told me to use code "G.add_nodes_from(1,2,3,4)." However, when it comes to subnetworks, the book gave an example. The code said:

```
K5 = nx.complete_graph(5)
clique = nx.subgraph(K5, (0,1,2))
```

My question is: for this network, why does the number of nodes start from 0? It is 0,1,2,3,4. Why is it not "1,2,3,4,5"? I'm confused.

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just by design. It is mentioned in the [docs](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.classic.complete_graph.html):

> Node labels are the integers 0 to n-1.

This is also coherent with indices in python (and other languages in general). The first index in python lists and other indexable iterables is always `0`.